# Ordinal exponentiation, is $3^\mu = \mu$?

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

I'm revising for my set theory final, and I've been asked to find an ordinal $\mu > \omega$ with $2^\mu = \mu$, then to answer whether $3^\mu = \mu$.

The ordinal I picked as $\mu$ was the union of all the ordinals $\mu_i$ where $\mu_0 = \omega + 1$ and $\mu_{n^+} = 2^{\mu_n}$.

I could show that then $2^\mu = \mu$, but I don't know whether $3^\mu = \mu$ or not, and I was wondering if anyone could help, either with the $\mu$ I picked, or with a different $\mu$ which is easier to work with. Another idea I had for $\mu$ was the limit of $\mu+0 = \omega$ and $\mu_{n^+} = \omega^{\mu_n}$, but I couldn't prove $2^\mu = \mu$ or not.

Thanks!

Comment: Your second $\mu$ is commonly called $\varepsilon_0$, and it has the property that $\omega^{\varepsilon_0}=\varepsilon_0$ (it is the smallest such ordinal, hence the $_0$).

Comment: For $\epsilon_0$, note $\alpha\le 2^\alpha\le 3^\alpha\le\omega^\alpha$ for any $\alpha>1$ (by induction), so if $\alpha=\omega^\alpha$, we actually have equalities.

Comment: In general, $2^\mu = \mu$ implies $3^\mu = \mu$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $2^\mu=\mu$, then $\mu$ is a limit; so $2^\mu\le 3^\mu\le 4^\mu=2^{(2\mu)}=2^\mu$. Note that a similar argument works with 2 and 3 replaced by any finite $m, n>1$.

Exercise: what about $m, n$ possibly infinite?